# Animate a curve in response to UIScrollView velocity

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview

I have a custom scroll view with a rectangle inside.

I would like to animate a curve along the top line of this rectangle so that it responds to scroll velocity. When done, it would look something like this:

video: http://capptivate.co/2015/02/01/skype-qik/

[image: still of curved scroll view]

How would I accomplish this? Both high-level approaches and specific implementations are welcome, I'm not sure how to get started. (core animation? drawrect?)

Comment: mesh transforms: more features than needed and private. http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/05/14/mesh-transforms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nicely explained here http://holko.pl/2014/06/26/recreating-skypes-action-sheet-animation/

You can use a bezier path (either in a custom `UIView` w/ `drawRect:`, or easier with a `CAShapeLayer`), whose curvature can be controlled via its control points. So change the control points based on the scrollview's offset and you should have this effect.

Comment: This was a great start for me. I think the approach is quite different between animating on a CAAnimation tick VS responding to scroll velocity. I found a velocity-based library in your link: https://github.com/brocoo/BRFlabbyTable/blob/master/Classes/BRFlabbyTableViewCell.m#L53

Comment: @SimplGy In scroll view you don't have to deal with any animation yourself, just change the control points in scrollViewDidScroll and you're all set.